# script to read image src

Tags: javascript

I am new to scripting and have spend a loy of time trying to write some code.

I want to read an certain images' dynamically written source and then write lower down on the page another image with a slightly different source like -

This image is dynamically written on the page at the top of the page

```
<img src="chrome.jpg" id="test1">
```

Then lower down I would like to write -

```
<img src="chrome2.jpg">
```

Would really appreciate amy help with this.

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

I *assume* with the 'page' you refer to a html page... And I further assume you want to do this on the client side...

You will need javascript for this, it makes sense to use a javascript library for tasks like that, things get easier this way. Using for example the jQuery library you can then use 'selectors' to identify and use dom tree elements and add or change everything you want. Something like:

```
source=$('img#test1').attr('src');
// do something with the source url contained now inside source
$('p#further_down').append('<img>).attr('src',source);
```

---

```
<html>
<head>  

  <!-- inclusion of the jQuery Javascript library -->
  <script 
    type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
  </script>

  <!-- this is 'your' function -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function doubleImg(){
      // you 'get' the source url of the upper image:
      var topSrc=$('#top img').attr('src');
      // no you can do something with that url
      // for this demo I replace the 'direction' inside the icons name: 
      var bottomSrc=topSrc.replace(/up/, 'down');
      // now you create a new <img> tag 
      // and 'set' the changed url as 'src' attribute:
      var img=$('<img width="100">').attr('src',bottomSrc);
      // and finally you 'add' that <img> tag into your dom tree ("the page"): 
      $('#bottom').append(img);
    }
  </script>

  <!-- this gets 'your' function executed ->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(doubleImg);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- the "top" frame, note that it DOES hold an <img> inside -->
  <fieldset id="top" style="border=2px solid green;">
    <legend>TOP</legend>
    <img width="100" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/128/Actions-arrow-up-icon.png">
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <!-- the "bottom" frame, note that it DOES NOT hold an <img> inside -->
  <fieldset id="bottom" style="border=2px solid blue;">
    <legend>BOTTOM</legend>
  </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi i tried this as below but no luck pls help  <img src="email_icon.jpg" id="test1" border="0" /><br><br>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
source=$('img#test1').attr('src');
// do something with the source url contained now inside source
$('p#further_down').append('<img>').attr('src,source');
</script>

Comment: Well, what I gave was just a rough example ("something _like_"). You have to adapt it to your needs. Never just copy what others give you, try to _understand_ what is is. Anyways: usually the JavaScript component is kept in a separate file that is referenced inside the html pages head. You will find millions of examples on google for that or for example the source code of _this_ page. If not you have to put the javascript source into the html head _and_ you have to make sure it is executed. I added a working example inside the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what do you mean by only scripting, so I’m providing two ways you can achieve your desire results, through `DOM` & through `jQuery`.

- `Using jQuery:`

Retrieve the `src of an image:

```
var src = $(“#test1”).attr('src');
```

Change the `src` of an image:

```
$("# test1").attr("src","chrome2.jpg");
```

- `Using DOM:`

Retrieve the `src of an image:

```
document.getElementById("test1").src;
```

Change the `src` of an image:

```
document.getElementById("test1").src="chrome2.jpg";
```

Hope it helps.